# setState() method in Flutter is not updating the view until the last call in a for loop

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate, statefulwidget

### The problem

I am trying to build a sorting visualizer using Flutter. I have used a `CustomPainter` to paint vertical lines that correspond to the values of the integer list that I intend to sort. 
The application is set up such that when a user clicks the "Bubble sort" option from the `DropDownButton`
(I intend to add more sorting algorithms later) the vertical lines in the `CustomPainter`'s Canvas must sort themselves.

### Code

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(HomePage());

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomePageSate createState() {
    return HomePageState();
  }
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<int> arr;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    arr = _getRandomIntegerList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Sorting Visualiser'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            DropdownButton<String>(
              onChanged: (dynamic choice) {
                switch (choice) {
                  case 'Bubble Sort':
                    _bubbleSortVisualiser();
                    break;
                }
              },
              items: <String>['Bubble Sort']
                  .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: Text(value),
                );
              }).toList(),
            )
          ],
        ),
        //The following flatButton refreshes arr to have a new array of random integers.
        bottomNavigationBar: FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              arr = _getRandomIntegerList();
            });
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
        ),
        body: CustomPaint(
          size: Size(double.infinity, double.infinity),
          painter: SortingCanvas(arr),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  //function to sort the list using bubble sort and repaint the canvas at every iteration.
  void _bubbleSortVisualiser() {
    print('Bubble sort function called');
    List<int> bubbleArr = List.from(arr);

    for (int i = 0; i < bubbleArr.length - 1; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < bubbleArr.length - 1 - i; j++) {
        int temp;
        if (bubbleArr[j] < bubbleArr[j + 1]) {
          temp = bubbleArr[j];
          bubbleArr[j] = bubbleArr[j + 1];
          bubbleArr[j + 1] = temp;
          //Every time arr changes setState() is called to visualise the changing array.
          setState(() {
            arr = List.from(bubbleArr);
            print("Updated to : $arr");
          });

          //Sleep is called so that the change is noticeable
          sleep(Duration(seconds: 1));

        }
      }
    }
  }
}

class SortingCanvas extends CustomPainter {
  List<int> arr;

  SortingCanvas(this.arr);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var linePaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 5.0
      ..isAntiAlias = true;
    //IMP the first offset is the bottom point and the second is the top point of the vertical line. 
    //It is offset from the top left corner of the canvas
    for (int i = 1; i <= arr.length; i++) {
      canvas.drawLine(Offset(50.0 + (20 * i), size.height - 50),
          Offset(50.0 + (20 * i), 50.0 * arr[i - 1]), linePaint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(SortingCanvas oldDelegate) {
    return !listEquals(this.arr, oldDelegate.arr);
  }
}

//Helper function to get a list of 10 random integers
List<int> _getRandomIntegerList() {
  List<int> arr = [];
  Random rng = new Random();

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    arr.add(rng.nextInt(10));
  }
  return arr;
}
```

However, what ends up occurring is that only the final sorted `arr` is visualized on the canvas and all the intermediate steps are skipped for some reason. But the log shows the list updating.

### Screenshots

The initial screen with the random list
[image]
Clicking bubble sort in the dropdown button
[image]
The sorted list
[image]

The `sleep()` function is added just to emulate an animation and I intend to replace it with a proper animation once this issue is resolved. Also, I am aware that the application is a tad ugly, but I would like to get the logic right before any UI polishing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Future.delay like

```
      void _bubbleSortVisualiser() async {
        print('Bubble sort function called');
        List<int> bubbleArr = List.from(arr);

        for (int i = 0; i < bubbleArr.length - 1; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < bubbleArr.length - 1 - i; j++) {
            int temp;
            if (bubbleArr[j] < bubbleArr[j + 1]) {
              temp = bubbleArr[j];
              bubbleArr[j] = bubbleArr[j + 1];
              bubbleArr[j + 1] = temp;
              //Every time arr changes setState() is called to visualise the changing array.
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      setState(() {
                arr = List.from(bubbleArr);
                print("Updated to : $arr");
              });
    });




        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep it works ! thank you. using sleep() was the wrong move after all.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
class HomePageState extends State<StatefulWidget> {
```

should be

```
class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
```

That's all. It should work then.

Also, you should change this:

```
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return HomePageState();
  }
```

to:

```
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => HomePageState();
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out these errors. I've corrected them but the problem still persists. What I'm looking for is a way to delay the intermediate repaints to the stateful widget. In any case I have edited the code in the question with your corrections. The way the app runs is : i press the dropdown button, The app seemingly freezes for a period of time and then the array on screen is directly converted into the sorted array

Comment: What setState() do you think is the issue? Also, did you try completely restarting the application?

Comment: The setState() within the _bubbleSortVisualizer() function. I'm using it to update the list member variable with the partially sorted list. And yes i have tried restarting the application but to no avail

Comment: Try extracting `List.from(bubbleArr)` into its own variable above it (not in `setState()`) and set `arr` equal to that.

Comment: Or a better approach is to modify the return type of `_bubbleSortVisualizer()` and return the `List.from(bubbleArr)` and set the state where you call the method.

Comment: I assume you mean like this : `List<int> partially_sorted_list = List.from(bubbleArr);
          setState(() {
            arr = partially_sorted_list;
            print("Updated to : $arr");
          });
` But the problem is still persisting

Comment: S In reference to your solution of changing the return type, I would still have to call setState() within a loop, only now it is within the switch case of the dropDownButton. Something like `while(isSorted(arr)){ arr = _bubbleSortVisualizer();  sleep(Duration(seconds:10)); }` The outcome would be the same since setSate() is still in a loop. (isSorted() is a hypothetical helper function ).